# How to align Html module title to right in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am developing a multilingual website (Arabic,English) using DotNetNuke last version and i have enabled the site localization so there are tow icons in the top of page , in the Html module i can align the content of the module to right using the editor , but the title still on the left , so how to align the title to the right? , i think i should edit the css files (default.css , container.css) but these files used by the English version also .

so What is the best solution to align the title to the right ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Radi, I haven't done multilanguage with right to left languages before. But here is something to look into. Typically in DNN when you switch between languages there are some new URL parameters  or DNN variables available.  In your skin you could do a check on language and include an extra CSS file that loads only for right to left languages and then in that CSS file do the alignment. Probably a better way, but that should work.